# Design a MySQL table(s) to store data of uploaded files

Tags: php, mysql

Im doing some redesigning of our database im building new tables to hold data about files users uploaded. The overlying issue here is that there are a bunch of different types of files users may upload. They may for example upload an mp3 file as a song, a profile picture, a profile cover photo, etc. Im running into a few design and practical issues, though, and am trying to figure out the best to do this. At the moment the main design looks something like this:

```
 ID | name | type | amazon_S3_info
```

**ID:** auto-increment an ID for every new upload. 
**name:** name of the upload i.e. file name for example 
**type:** what type of upload it is, for example a profile picture, a cover photo, audio file etc. 
**amazon_S3_info:**  Im storing all the files in an S3 and this field holds the data so I can generate the URL. I can't store a URL here, since im using signed urls and they always need to be regenerated with the data stored in this field.

After creating a table like this I could then just make matching tables where I, for example, create the relationships between a user ID and the upload ID of the profile picture they uploaded, etc. which is pretty simple.

My original idea was to break this whole thing up into multiple tables, meaning I would make 1 table for profile pictures, 1 for cover photos, etc. The reason this would become a bit of a headache on the php-side is that I have one standard function which uses an ID to retrieve the file URL for these files. If I have multiple tables then each type of upload would have 1 of the same ID in it, thus rendering my current URL retrieval useless. This is already in use all over the site and would be a nuisance to redo, however if it needs to it needs to be.

To be clear the idea here to break up into a few tables was speed. My logic is that it would more efficient to break a single table that could be 2,000,000 rows into a 4 tables of 500,000. It would be quicker to pull data from each one of those 500,000 rows table, or is that a false premise?

So my question to you lot is which database design is better, particularly when we are talking about scaling to be quite large?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With databases (and computers in general), you're usually worried about factors of 10, not just 2x or 3x.

So splitting up the table by type into multiple tables, say 5 tables altogether instead of 1, ultimately won't solve your performance issues once the data grows extremely large.  And like you said, it's a programming pain.  (Basically you'd be sharding manually without an algorithm...if going to shard might as well use a hash shard algorithm to find the database/table).

The design you have is standard many to many.  Index the tables correctly and that's the best you can do.

If performance becomes a problem, you need to scale horizontally.  Relational datastores don't do this well, but NoSQL datastores do.  You can have those types of references in NoSQL as well.  If design changes are still possible, look into AWS DynamoDB (NoSQL service).

Edit: to respond to a comment...

@arian1123 In my experience, there's a point (table size) where all of a sudden mysql starts performing poorly.  The more hardware (especially memory) you have, the larger the tables can grow before this happens.  (The killer are joins.  If you don't join big tables on big tables, then a big table by itself probably can grow very large with adequate hardware, I've dealt with 1Billion+ row tables where only reads were done with no joins, and it wasn't a problem.)

On your own laptop, you may see 100k tables performing fine, and 1M tables not.  If the data isn't going to grow anymore and that's the power of hardware you'll have on production, then splitting would be a good idea.  However if you're going to always be increasing table size, like 50M as you mention, then splitting it up would only help if you could split indefinetly (like every 2 million rows you divide the table again).  In you're case you aren't wanting to continue to divide 1 table to 4 to 20 to 100...so I think it'd be better to leave as 1 table, and if it doesn't perform then look into other datastore types.

Comment: Cool thanks for that answer, just one point of clarification in your opinion: when I say to make it scale more easily I was more thinking along the lines that it may be simple to have 4 tables with 500,000 rows each than having to pull data from 1 table with 2,000,000 rows.. or is that a false premise?

Comment: @arian1123 Depends how you're indexing and keeping it organized between the 4 tables. I would suspect you'd need additional work to handle that, which might negate any performance gain from splitting it. Two million rows isn't that big though, I would just stick with one table.

Comment: @jhaagsma the indexing system would be same across all tables like it is in the one larger table. The bigger issue for me personally is the PHP-side. I would need to change 1 function into many different ones that I use in different cases as well redo basically all of the files processing etc. So thats a pain. What extra work would you think might be needed to handle the extra tables?

Comment: Also as for the amount of rows I do want to prepare that total uploads could go way upwards of 50,000,000+. thats the sort of size im trying to plan for so I would imagine breaking that down could make a world of difference?

Comment: You can use table partitioning or merge table engine to achive what you want. This way you do not have the overhead of maintaining separate tables, but can benefit from smaller table sizes.

Comment: @arian1123 Basically my argument is that splitting to only 4 ultimately will have the same issue as just 1.  If you have trouble with 1 table at 10M rows, splitting to four 2.5M row tables may help in the short term (depending on the hardware it's running on), but ultimately those 4 tables will each grow to 10M anyway and have a problem then.

Comment: @gimbel0893 fair enough. Going to stick with the 1 table. Thanks a lot.